# Prevent merge of dataframes from dropping data and replacing with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, nan

I have two df I wish to merge. Examples:

dfone

```
    Centre  Name    open  click
0   12345   Ed      4     7
1   67890   Dave    8     3
2   54321   Mary    5     6
3   09876   Susan   4     3
4   24680   Tom     9     7
5   13579   Will    6     2
```

dftwo

```
    Centre  Name    Train  Online Home
0   67890   Dave    Y      Y      N
1   13579   Will    N      Y      Y
2   09876   Susan   Y      Y      Y
3   24680   Tom     N      N      Y
4   54321   Mary    Y      Y      N
5   12345   Ed      N      N      N
```

I use the following to merge the two dfs:

```
dfthree = pd.merge(dfone, dftwo, left_on='Centre', right_on='Centre', how='left',
                  suffixes=('','_y')).filter(regex='^(?!.*_y)')
```

My desired output is:

```
    Centre  Name    open  click  Train  Online Home
0   12345   Ed      4     7      N      N      N
1   67890   Dave    8     3      Y      Y      N
2   54321   Mary    5     6      Y      Y      N
3   09876   Susan   4     3      Y      Y      Y
4   24680   Tom     9     7      N      N      Y
5   13579   Will    6     2      N      Y      Y
```

My ACTUAL output is:

```
    Centre  Name    open  click  Train  Online Home
0   12345   Ed      4     7      N      N      N
1   67890   Dave    8     3      N      N      N
2   54321   Mary    5     6      N      N      N
3   09876   Susan   4     3      Nan    Nan    Nan
4   24680   Tom     9     7      Nan    Nan    Nan
5   13579   Will    6     2      Nan    Nan    Nan
```

Where am I going wrong please and what should I be doing instead?

Comment: I don't reproduce your issue (python 3.11, pandas 2.0.0), the desired output is obtained. What are your python/pandas versions?

Comment: I can't reproduce either with python 3.9.0 and pandas 2.0.0

Comment: You can get the desired result simply with the following code `dfthree = pd.merge(dfone, dftwo,  how='left')` Also, if the merge result is NaN instead of the desired result, the actual data is the same when I see it with my eyes, but in reality it is often different. ex) white space, case, data type, etc.

Comment: @PandaKim I don't understand the second part of your response unfortunately - Your suggested code does merge but I still have the same problem with the data from dftwo - the top three rows all show N which is not correct and the rest of the data has disappeared leaving only NaN.

Comment: @EdJefferies try to remove possible spaces in the rows dfone['Name'] = dfone['Name'].str.strip() and
dftwo['Name'] = dftwo['Name'].str.strip(). And if Center has a string type, then you need to do the same with it. You can find out the data type of columns like this: print(dfone.dtypes) rows are of type object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Centre': {0: 12345, 1: 67890, 2: 54321, 3: 9876, 4: 24680, 5: 13579},
 'Name': {0: 'Ed', 1: 'Dave', 2: 'Mary', 3: 'Susan', 4: 'Tom', 5: 'Will'},
 'open': {0: 4, 1: 8, 2: 5, 3: 4, 4: 9, 5: 6},
 'click': {0: 7, 1: 3, 2: 6, 3: 3, 4: 7, 5: 2}}

data2 = {'Centre': {0: 67890, 1: 13579, 2: 9876, 3: 24680, 4: 54321, 5: 12345},
 'Name': {0: 'Dave', 1: 'Will', 2: 'Susan', 3: 'Tom', 4: 'Mary', 5: 'Ed'},
 'Train': {0: 'Y', 1: 'N', 2: 'Y', 3: 'N', 4: 'Y', 5: 'N'},
 'Online': {0: 'Y', 1: 'Y', 2: 'Y', 3: 'N', 4: 'Y', 5: 'N'},
 'Home': {0: 'N', 1: 'Y', 2: 'Y', 3: 'Y', 4: 'N', 5: 'N'}}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

**Code**

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='left')
```

`df3`

```
    Centre  Name    open    click   Train   Online  Home
0   12345   Ed      4       7       N       N       N
1   67890   Dave    8       3       Y       Y       N
2   54321   Mary    5       6       Y       Y       N
3   9876    Susan   4       3       Y       Y       Y
4   24680   Tom     9       7       N       N       Y
5   13579   Will    6       2       N       Y       Y
```

Applying the code to an well-made example before you apply it to your dataset will reveal the cause of most problems. Your problem is not a problem with code.

if the merge result is NaN instead of the desired result, the actual data is the same when you see it with your eyes, but in reality it is often different.

ex) white space, case, data type, etc.

'abc' ≠ ' abc'

'abc' ≠ 'Abc'

1 ≠ '1'

`merge` need exact same key, unless return NaN. The ex above is a typical example of what we think is the same key but different.